# Help regarding JoomFish

Tags: joomla1.5, joomfish

I am new to joomla and wanted to use JoomFish for multi-lingual support. Can anyone please let me know details of how can we use JoomFish to translate the site content. Also how can we translate the content of customly developed components / modules. Also how can we translate the static content in the components/modules i.e. the label which are used statically?

Can any one provide any reference which has a good understanding of doing the above mentioned things.

Regards,
Atul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomfish does not do any translation, all of it has to be entered by the admin. It takes a bit of configuration - language packs have to be installed, extension content elements need to be translated, etc. Your best bet is to install it on your site and go through the tutorials.

http://www.joomfish.net/en/documentation/tutorials

There is no shortcut that could easily be entered as an answer here.